# Rails: Purchases vs Orders

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, relational-database

I have an eccomerce app. I have `buyers` & `sellers` (same table). A buyer `has_many :purchases` & a seller `has_many :orders`, right? But what about guest buyers (not signed in)? Should I merge "orders" & "purchases" table & make a "transactions" table? I want to get both a buyer's orders & a seller's purchases & some that are rather complex.

I'm not new to rails or databases but am ***sort of burned out at the moment.. Could someone break this down for me? (2 yr old style)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. You need to rethink this completely.

You should have a separate table for EVERYTHING so that you can have more detailed information. There should be a table for:

Orders - With an order_id, a Time/Date Stamp of the order, who the buyer was, who the seller was, what the method of payment was, what the product was, and what the price was

Buyers - As referenced in Orders. Here you will find all the relevant information for each buyer. In this way it doesn't matter if the buyer is a registered user or not because there will be two fields: buyer_id, and user_id.  If the buyer isn't a registered user... then that field will just be blank. Then you will have references for that buyer's purchases and most of the rest will be found in Orders

Sellers - Sellers, of course, HAVE to be registered users. So really you could just have this information in the Users table, but I like to keep e-commerce stuff separate for security reasons. Basically the same info only with user_id as a seller_id isn't really necessary. Then a list of sales, a reference to the products sold, the amounts sold, a reference to the orders, etc.

Products - Pretty self-explanatory.

The rest is up to you. but that's the basics. Buyer, Seller, Product, Order. They should all be their own tables.

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question directly, but it should hopefully give you some ideas

---

**Model Distribution**

We always try and keep models as distributed as possible -- I.E if you can split a model into two separate ones, do so

Our reason for this is extensibility -- it's more efficient to extend smaller models, than to try and accommodate everything into one; allowing you to do lots of different things later on. Convention also dictates that a "data model" is that -- a model for a particular dataset

For you, I'd recommend splitting your models like this:

```
#app/models/buyer.rb
Class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders, :class_name => 'Order'
end

#app/models/seller.rb
Class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders, :class_name => 'Order'
end

#app/models/order.rb
Class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :buyer :class_name => 'Buyer'
    belongs_to :seller, :class_name => 'Seller'

    has_many :order_products, :class_name => 'OrderProduct'
    has_many :products, :class_name => 'Product', :through => :order_products
end
```

This will allow you to call `@buyer.orders`, where the `Order` table will look like this:

```
Order Table
id | buyer_id | seller_id | any | extra | columns | created_at | updated_at
```

---

**Extend Order With a [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) Table**

If you have a products table, you can give `orders` a number of products by using the `has_many :through` association. This is where you create a `join model` to give your orders as many products as it needs, without encumbering the orders model in any way

Here's how this may look:

```
order_products
id | order_id | product_id | delivery_notes | created_at | updated_at
```